# Safe way of registering GCM ID in serverside?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

What is the most standard and safe way of registering GCM ID's in serverside?

If I expose a URL like this:

`https://...../api/subscriptions/register`

Which receives the GCM ID and (for example) email, and then stores in a database, eg:

`https://...../api/subscriptions/register?gcmId=......&email=.....`

My Android application can call that URL (programatically) and I know that I don't have to worry about *Men In The Middle* because the URL is being called with HTTPS (SSL) and so the request is encrypted....

**...BUT :**
I'm still worried about the fact that if someone knows that URL (eg. suppose the project is open source), they can do fake registrations (`?gcmId=trash&email=trash`) or they can register valid emails with their own GCM ID (`?gcmId=my_own_id&email=my_friend_email`)

What is the standard way of securing this?